Interpolation of points of a scatterplot
I have big issues when trying using packages that interpolate between data points.
I want to obtain a smooth curve out of my discrete data and to perform derivatives on them.
The data set is this:
using Images, Plots, ImageFiltering, Colors, Statistics, TestImages, ScatteredInterpolation, GMT

img10 = testimage("water_512.tiff")
img11 = testimage("moonsurface.tiff")
img12 = testimage("wood_grain_he_512.tiff")
img13 = testimage("blobs.gif")
img14 = testimage("fabio_gray_512.png")
img15 = testimage("jetplane.tif")

function average_color_gray(window)
    return mean(window)
end

function color_std_gray(values)
    return std(values)
end
color_means = []
function calculate_std_over_windows_gray(img, window_size)
    h, w = size(img)
    for i in 1:window_size:h-window_size+1
        for j in 1:window_size:w-window_size+1
            window = img[i:i+window_size-1, j:j+window_size-1]
            mean_color = average_color_gray(window)
            push!(color_means, mean_color)
        end
    end
    # Calcola la deviazione standard dei colori medi
    std_dev = color_std_gray(color_means)
    return std_dev
end
window_sizes = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048]

std_devss = []
std_devs = []
# Calcola la deviazione standard per ciascuna dimensione di finestra
for size in window_sizes
    if size < min(width(img10), height(img10))
        std_dev = calculate_std_over_windows_gray(img10, size)
        push!(std_devs, std_dev)
    end
end

std_devss = std_devs[.!isnan.(std_devs)]
wind_siz = window_sizes[1:length(std_devss)]
ss = log.(1 ./ std_devss)

Plots.plot(1:9, ss)
Plots.scatter!(1:9, ss)

the result of this code should be a scatter plot of 9 points making a sigmoid, But I cannot succed in creating a smooth curve that approximate my data.
I tried to use Interpolations.jl, Dierckx.jl, ScatteredInterpolation,jl ... but I always obtain errors saying that the method doesn't mach or that the functions don't exist. Even copy-pasting the documentation's examples return errors.

It would help a lot to see the scatter plot and have a minimal reproducible example of that part of the problem. The code posted requires access to too much external data. Numerical differentiation is almost always doomed to fail on noisy data - it is hard enough to do it well by difference methods even on smooth analytical functions.

Hi, sorry you were right the code was incomplete. I edited and fixed it, so it should work. Anyway my data are not noisy at all, the're pretty clean and probably it's easy to find a function we can interpole them with... I just need more points because my data are around 9-10 points and to find a slope or peak would be extremely imprecise.

Fixed a few typos in the code, however there's no error due to interpolation in this version.

This seems to make the plot for me with slight modifications:
using Plots, Statistics, TestImages

function calculate_std_over_windows_gray(img, window_size)
    h, w = size(img)
    color_means = []
    for i in 1:window_size:h-window_size+1
        for j in 1:window_size:w-window_size+1
            window = img[i:i+window_size-1, j:j+window_size-1]
            mean_color = mean(window)
            push!(color_means, mean_color)
        end
    end

    # Calcola la deviazione standard dei colori medi
    std_dev = std(color_means)
    return std_dev
end

img10 = testimage("water_512.tiff")

window_sizes = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048]
std_devs = []

# Calcola la deviazione standard per ciascuna dimensione di finestra
for wsize in window_sizes
    if wsize < min(size(img10)...)
        std_dev = calculate_std_over_windows_gray(img10, wsize)
        push!(std_devs, std_dev)
    end
end

std_devss = std_devs[.!isnan.(std_devs)]
wind_siz = window_sizes[1:length(std_devss)]
ss = log.(1 ./ std_devss)

Plots.plot(1:9, ss)
Plots.scatter!(1:9, ss)


Not sure if that is what you wanted though.
Now if you would like to not just connect the points but have a function that can interpolate between the given points here is a sample piece of code you can modify for your use:
using Interpolations
yvals = [4.59302, 4.743, 5.48149, 6.31875, 7.11668, 7.76461, 8.20345, 8.53243, 8.39479]
cubic_interp = cubic_spline_interpolation(1:9, yvals);
scatter(1:9, yvals, label="Data points")
xvals = range(1, 9, step=0.2)
plot!(xvals, cubic_interp.(xvals), label="Interpolated")



That's exactly one of my plots. What I need tho is a function of a smooth curve that interpolate my data points. So I can calculate the flex point with more 'precision' than using just 9 points. I see tutorials with Interpolations.jl that show a plot with the calculated smooth curve overlapping the scatter plot but I can't write such a code

In that case, you can pass in the variable ss to the interpolation library. I have added an example to the answer.

Oh I see, thanks. Anyway I copied your exact code and I get  the error:
'''
Julia> cubic_interp = Interpolations.cubic_spline_interpolation(1:9, yvals);
ERROR: UndefVarError: cubic_spline_interpolation not defined
'''
whatever I do, also copying the very same code, I get this
